# PDO INSERT Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-insert

when I run this code :

```
$req = $conn->query('SELECT max(id_work) FROM work');
$res = $req->fetchColumn();
$current_id = $res['id_work'];

$desired_dir="images/work/" . $max . "-" . $_POST['title'] . "/";

$req = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO screenshot(link_screenshot, id_work) 
                              VALUES (:link, :id_work)');
$req->execute(array(
                    'link_screenshot' => $desired_dir . "/" . $file_name,
                    'id_work' => $current_id));  //Line where I get from the error
```

I get this error :

> **Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp\www\pcqsp-scratch\admin.php on line 82**

line 82 : `'id_work' => $current_id));`

Do you have any idea about this ? Thank you :)

Comment: Your query includes `:link`, but your array gives it the name `link_screenshot`. Change them both to the same name.

Comment: Thank you @andrewsi I've wasted too many time on this and didn't even notice that..